# Why are VLC-videos grey, but get colored as soon as I open them with Totem?

Tags: ubuntu, video, vlc-media-player, totem

I am using Ubuntu 10.10 with vlc 1.1.4 and totem 2.32.0.

I have seen the following, strange behaviour several times:
When I open a video in VLC it is gray:

[image: Video in VLC before I open them with totem]

As soon as I open the same video in totem, the video opened in VLC gets colored:
edit: It even hasn't to be the same video. It can be any video file that I open with Totem.

[image]

Why is this happening? How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your default VLC Settings either have a high Gamma Correct applied or a combination of High Brightness and Low Contrast, and that somehow Totem is overriding or adjusting these when it opens.  Check your VLC video settings are correct.

Comment: Where can I find the video settings? If I use the GUI, I can find only a few settings. Nothing changes there.